# Identify multiple polylines in one polygon (ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, line, attribute-joins

I have coastal city polygons, and one polyline with a numeric attribute (X) that I am interested in, which ranges from 1-9. One city can have diverse values of X. My final goal is to have one table, with the cities in one column, and all their respective X values (1-9), in another column, or in multiple columns.

An example image of the diverse occurrence of X in one city

[image]

Comment: Do you want to record all of the X values for each city? Or only a statistic (max/min/mean) for the X values? In general you're interested in some form of spatial intersect, identifying which lines fall within a given city. From there you could count the X values (yes/no if they occur or the number that occur for a given X value), or run a summary statistic (max X, min X, etc.) depending on your desired output.

Comment: Yes, I would like to record all of X values for each city. I have tried all of the join tool possibilities, intersection and closest, joining X to city and the other way around. None of those have worked.

Comment: Edit your question to give the details of what you've tried, and where these attempts failed (either by producing a different result than you want or with actual errors).